# Star Trek episode featuring a planet with battling robots and two teens, the only humans

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

I'm trying to locate a specific episode of the Original Star Trek with William Shatner as Captain Kirk. It is about 3 or 4 members of the crew who beam down to a planet and find giant robots battling each other. With investigation they discover two teenagers, each in a separate building, who have never seen another human being in their lives, not even each other. They are the only remaining humans on the planet.

Comment: Finding children / teenagers in buildings and no other humans on the planet is a plot point in the season one episode "Miri" but there are certainly no giant robots fighting each other, and the children all know one another. There is no TOS episode with "giant" robots fighting each other. There is an episode with a large robot, "Ruk" in Season 1 "What are Little Girls Made Of?" (played by the same actor as 'Lurch' from the Addams Family series)

Comment: could also be possibly conflating the opening of season 1 "Arena" where there are large bombs going off from an unknown source and the planet is effectively dead

Comment: I believe the OP is getting the TOS episode "Let That Be Your Last Battlefield" mixed up with the SeaQuest DSV episode "Playtime". That's the only possibility that I can think of

Comment: "Let That Be Your Last Battlefield" is nothing at all like anything that is described @SpacePhoenix and is itself uniquely distinctive in its makeup for the guest characters. It's almost entirely isolated to the ship, there are no children, robots, etc... (and again, the iconic makeup of the guest actors). Maybe you mean "A Taste of Armageddon"? Where the away team comes across a war waged by computer? Not familar with the Seaquest episode. That could be a helpful detail

Comment: NOT A STAR TREK OS -- I once from memory with another guy listed all 79 original series episode. NOT EVEN CLOSE,  these elements don't even exist in two separate episodes.

Answer (score 18):

This is a real long shot because the timing on when it aired would not at all match the Star Trek-TOS timeframe.  But, I believe rather than Star Trek I believe you are referring to the [SeaQuest episode Playtime](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0696935/)

Points that match include:

1. There only being two teenaged humans left on Earth.

   *"A distant call for help pulls the SeaQuest through an underwater anomaly, propelling the boat 225 years into the future where they find that mankind has destroyed itself, leaving only two teenaged kids as the only Human life left on Earth."*
2. The title "Playtime."

   *Because they have never actually met each other, the two teenagers remotely control robots to battle each other in a continuous playing mode.*

   As commented by a viewer on the IMDB site:

   *"The first 15 minutes of this episode are OK, the time travel, the remains of human society, a supercomputer and mechwarrior-like robots fighting (although those were cheap CGI-effects, but still worth a watch)."*
3. Beaming down.

   *A partial match that you may be mis-remembering, rather than beaming down, the crew actually travels through a black hole in time to reach them.*

Comment: good answer! Hattip to @SpacePhoenix who first brought up this episode in a comment