Looking for a movie or made for tv film or miniseries that I saw in the 80s. Featuring VR and the decline of humanity
All I remember of the plot is this: Humanity is addicted to these VR machines. We all live our lives in VR and never meet IRL. As a result no one is having sex or kids anymore, population is dying. These two teens meet on VR and somehow escape their VR pods (big machines, mechanical looking that everyone is hooked to). The movie ends with them meeting IRL, holding hands, walking off together with the implication that they will be the couple to repopluate the world. Any ideas what film, or miniseries or made for tv thing this was? Saw it in the 80s on normal TV.

I don't think it's what you're looking for, so not adding it as an answer, but this plot has a lot of similarities with Ready Player One, which had a much more recent movie. I haven't watched the movie, but I read the book, and it features a number of the same premises around everyone interacting in VR and a few main protagonists meeting in person toward the end of the book.

A little bit later, but would loosely match the season 2 episode Playtime of Seaquest DSV, first shown in 1994.
The Seaquest travels 225 years in to the future, where humanity has mostly given up meeting in person in favour of interacting (mostly battling) in VR. The last two people alive - conveniently one male, one female, and both teenagers - are persuaded to start interacting in person again.
I last watched the show probably 15 years ago so detailed memories are a bit hazy. Having found a set of badly dubbed clips, the penultimate scene does appear to show them walking off hand-in-hand.

This is what I was thinking of, as VR didn't really start seeing usage in science fiction until the early 90s. Then practically every sci-fi series had to have an episode featuring it. This was Seaquest's one foray. As I recall the two teens are left alone holding hands, like described.

Sounds like what I remember! I will watch it tonight and let you know, thanks!

Episode previously here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235880/star-trek-episode-featuring-a-planet-with-battling-robots-and-two-teens-the-onl/235894#235894
